# Flutter Scheduled Daily Notification Change Title body for each time app notifies

Tags: flutter, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications, uilocalnotification

i have developed app which has daily temperature notification as functionality.

I am able to implement scheduled daily notification at specific time, i need to change value of  title and body for each time the schedule triggers

Is it possible to implement using flutter local-notification / flutter awesome notification, or should we depend on alarm plugin to trigger local notification

```
        /// IN Main.dart /////
        // @pragma('vm:entry-point')
        void scheduleBackgroundProcess() async {
          await NotificationService.showNotification(
            title: 'Temperature $dateToday',  ////// need to change this value for each trigger
            body: 'Temperature: $derivedTemperature', ////// need to change this value for each       trigger
            scheduled: true,
          );
        }


        /////// My Notification Service
        class NotificationService {
        static Future<void> initializeNotification() async {
          await AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
            null,
            [
              NotificationChannel(
                channelGroupKey: 'high_importance_channel',
                channelKey: 'high_importance_channel',
                channelName: 'Basic notifications',
                channelDescription: 'Notification channel for basic tests',
                defaultColor: const Color(0xFF9D50DD),
                ledColor: Colors.white,
                importance: NotificationImportance.Max,
                channelShowBadge: true,
                onlyAlertOnce: true,
                playSound: true,
                criticalAlerts: true,
              )
            ],
            channelGroups: [
              NotificationChannelGroup(
                channelGroupKey: 'high_importance_channel_group',
                channelGroupName: 'Group 1',
              )
            ],
            debug: true,
          );
        }

          await AwesomeNotifications().isNotificationAllowed().then(
            (isAllowed) async {
              if (!isAllowed) {
                await AwesomeNotifications().requestPermissionToSendNotifications();
              }
            },
          );

          await AwesomeNotifications().setListeners(
            onActionReceivedMethod: onActionReceivedMethod,
            onNotificationCreatedMethod: onNotificationCreatedMethod,
            onNotificationDisplayedMethod: onNotificationDisplayedMethod,
            onDismissActionReceivedMethod: onDismissActionReceivedMethod,
          );
        }

        /// Use this method to detect when a new notification or a schedule is created
        static Future<void> onNotificationCreatedMethod(
            ReceivedNotification receivedNotification) async {
          debugPrint('onNotificationCreatedMethod');
        }

        /// Use this method to detect every time that a new notification is displayed
        static Future<void> onNotificationDisplayedMethod(
            ReceivedNotification receivedNotification) async {
          debugPrint('onNotificationDisplayedMethod');
        }

        /// Use this method to detect if the user dismissed a notification
        static Future<void> onDismissActionReceivedMethod(
            ReceivedAction receivedAction) async {
          debugPrint('onDismissActionReceivedMethod');
        }

        /// Use this method to detect when the user taps on a notification or action button
        static Future<void> onActionReceivedMethod(
            ReceivedAction receivedAction) async {
          debugPrint('onActionReceivedMethod');
          final payload = receivedAction.payload ?? {};
          if (payload["navigate"] == "true") {
            MyApp.navigatorKey.currentState?.push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (_) => const homePage(),
              ),
            );
          }
        }

      static Future<void> showNotification({
          required final String title,
          required final String body,
          final String? summary,
          final Map<String, String>? payload,
          final ActionType actionType = ActionType.Default,
          final NotificationLayout notificationLayout = NotificationLayout.Default,
          final NotificationCategory? category,
          final String? bigPicture,
          final List<NotificationActionButton>? actionButtons,
          final bool scheduled = false,
          final int? interval,
        }) async {
          assert(!scheduled || (scheduled && interval != null));

          await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
            content: NotificationContent(
              id: 0,
              channelKey: 'high_importance_channel',
              title: title,  ////// need to change this value for each trigger
              body: body, ////// need to change this value for each trigger
              actionType: actionType,
              summary: summary,
              category: category,
              payload: payload,
              bigPicture: 'asset://assets/bigpicture.png',
              largeIcon: 'asset://assets/logonotify.png',
              notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.BigPicture,
            ),
            actionButtons: actionButtons,
            //// Daily Schedule notification
            schedule: scheduled
                ? NotificationCalendar(
                    hour: 3,
                    minute: 30,
                    allowWhileIdle: true,
                    repeats: true,
                    timeZone:
                        await AwesomeNotifications().getLocalTimeZoneIdentifier(),
                    preciseAlarm: true)
                : null,
          );
        }

        static Future<void> resetBadgeCounter() async {
          await AwesomeNotifications().resetGlobalBadge();
        }

        static Future<void> cancelNotifications() async {
          await AwesomeNotifications().cancelAll();
        }
`
```